# How to connect to SharePoint online to run some PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

How can connect to SharePoint online to run some PowerShell commands? It would be nice if someone has drilled down the steps for me :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Connecting to SharePoint Online**
>
> Before you connect to SharePoint Online, you’ll need to have the
> username and password for an account with global administrator
> permissions.  You’ll also need to know your tenant admin URL (i.e.:
> `https://mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com`). When connecting to
> SharePoint Online, don’t forget to reference all URLs securely using
> https.If you try and use http, you will get an error. To connect to
> SharePoint Online, use the **Connect-SPOService** command. It takes the
> URL to your tenant admin and a username.  When you connect, you’ll be
> prompted for your password.
>
> ```
> Connect-SPOService –Url https://mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com –Credential admin@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com
> ```
>
> [image: SPO Management Shell]
>
> If you connect successfully, you will be returned to the command
> prompt without error. To see what commands are available, we can use
> Get-Command and pass it the module **Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.dll**

Source:
https://web.archive.org/web/20190301143657/http://dotnet.sys-con.com/node/2465770

Comment: Do we really need to be a global admin for everything? Say just reading and creating folders on a site where the user has full-control? Do we still need to be global admin?

Comment: Please check out some other methods described here that will also save you some extra time: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/wiki/How-to-use-the-Windows-Credential-Manager-to-ease-authentication-with-PnP-PowerShell

Comment: @NickN. You don't need to be an Office 365 Global Admin to use PowerShell with SPO, you just need to be a SharePoint Online Admin. Microsoft recommends only one person in an organization be a Global Admin because of the reaching access that permission level has. See more info here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to these two links from MSDN; they show everything you need to know about SharePoint Online and PowerShell.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161362(v=office.15)

and to your issue of how to setup PowerShell for SharePoint Online:

> 1. Install Windows PowerShell 3.0 from Windows Management Framework 3.0.
> 2. Install the SharePoint Online Management Shell from the Microsoft Download Center.
> 3. Click Start>All Programs>SharePoint Online Management Shell.
> 4. Run Connect-SPOService. For example, Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -credential admin@contoso.com,
>      where:
>        •  Url is the URL of the SharePoint Online Administration
>      Center.
>
>    •  Credential is the user name to which you want to grant access to
>      the SharePoint Online Administration Center site.
> 5. Try it out! For example, run Get-SPOSite to get a list of all sites.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161372

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but you can use the project **Client-Side SharePoint Powershell** http://sharepointpowershell.codeplex.com/ as a PowerShell API to SharePoint Online. The features still need to grow, but you can extend it yourself pretty easy and otherwise just request some features.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to install PowerShell depending on the bitness of your windows.
2. Install Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant for IT Professionals
3. install Windows Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell

and test it.

Reference & for more details: https://ziaahmedshaikh.wordpress.com/2015/09/11/configure-windows-powershell-to-connect-with-o356/

Comment: So sorry, wrong url pasted above. correct one is: https://ziaahmedshaikh.wordpress.com/2015/09/11/configure-windows-powershell-to-connect-with-o356/