# Create Online SharePoint 2013 site using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have online sharepoint 2013 subscription and my task is to create one sharepoint site using powerhsell. I have downloaded the Powers-hell for Online sharepoint 2013 for doing power-shell scripting ,But unable to move further. Can any one help me how can I achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below Powershell script will send the request to SharePoint and your site will be created.  Running the script won’t yield any output.

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\folder\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path "c:\folder\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$siteUrl = “https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitecollection”

$username = "admin@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com"

$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)

$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)

$ctx.Credentials = $credentials

$webCreationInformation = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebCreationInformation

$webCreationInformation.Url = "site1"

$webCreationInformation.Title = "Site 1"

$webCreationInformation.WebTemplate = "STS#0"

$newWeb = $ctx.Web.Webs.Add($webCreationInformation)

$ctx.Load($newWeb)

$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$newWeb

Write-Host "Title" $newWeb.Title
```

[Source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/04/24/create-and-manage-sharepoint-online-sites-by-using-powershell.aspx)

Comment: Hi Kartik thanks for your code.But can you please help me how can I run the entire code into 1 line

Comment: @mdsiddiqali, kindly have a look at this link, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55526/how-to-connect-to-sharepoint-online-to-run-some-powershell

Comment: HI Kartik ,
 At "$ctx.ExecuteQuery()" I am getting error as below
"Exception Calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" arguments(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
+$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
   +CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:) [],MethodInvocationException
   +FullyQualifiedErrorId :WebException" .
Can you please help me why I am facing this issue and how can I solve this

Comment: have a look at the below links, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342533/using-the-sharepoint-csom-with-powershell, http://blog.blumenthalit.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=171

Comment: Are the Credentials provided are proper, does the provided Credentials has required permission to create site.?